# Appropriate Method To Compare Groups

Tags: p-value, proportion

```
df=data.frame("var1"=sample(1:3,100,r=T),
          "var2"=sample(1:7,100,r=T),
          "var3"=sample(0:1,100,r=T),
          "group"=sample(1:2,100,r=T),
          "idweight"=sample(20:40,100,r=T))
```

This is my sample data. I have various categorical measures and I intend to test if there are statistically significant differences in their proportions by group (1 or 2). All of the students come from the same school but some of them opted for summer immersement programs. We are interested to see what factors are different among those who did and did not wish to do so.

In my education program I learned about logistic regression but we did not cover any basic descriptive analysis...so I am wondering 2 things. First is, what is an appropriate descriptive analysis to conduct? Second is, is it possible to estimate the p value from the descriptive analysis simultaneously for all of the different variables? I shall also add, our schools use student weights to make our locality representative of the larger 'county'

Comment: I see it is being voted to close this question, is this the wrong place to post it? Any feedback is helpful here...

Answer (score 1):

A good quick way to compare differences between groups across multiple variables is a multivariate t-test. The `car` package can execute such a procedure, and run the approximate F-test to derive accurate p-values (many other methods, such the 'lm' function will misreport p-values by executing sequential bivariate t-tests).

```
#note, using `lm` function with `cbind` to "trick" R into executing mulitvariate anova
#Then pass the result to the `Manova` function to execute a multivariate T-Test
#Lastly, pipe it into a summary to get the following output
car::Manova(lm(cbind(df[,"var1"],df[,"var2"],df[,"var3"]) ~ as.factor(df$group))) %>% summary()

Type II MANOVA Tests:

Sum of squares and products for error:
            [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  68.1104442 -23.13445   0.1260504
[2,] -23.1344538 372.62745 -17.2549020
[3,]   0.1260504 -17.25490  24.5098039

------------------------------------------

Term: as.factor(df$group) 

Sum of squares and products for the hypothesis:
            [,1]        [,2]          [,3]
[1,]  0.07955582 -0.50554622  0.0039495798
[2,] -0.50554622  3.21254902 -0.0250980392
[3,]  0.00394958 -0.02509804  0.0001960784

Multivariate Tests: as.factor(df$group)
                 Df test stat  approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
Pillai            1 0.0091611 0.2958655      3     96 0.8283
Wilks             1 0.9908389 0.2958655      3     96 0.8283
Hotelling-Lawley  1 0.0092458 0.2958655      3     96 0.8283
Roy               1 0.0092458 0.2958655      3     96 0.8283
```

Your p-values for the various versions of the multivariate t-test test statistics, unsurprisingly are all the same value, and clearly the random data shows no group differences, p = 0.83